# powershell check url https ignore certificate with nssm

Tags: powershell

I have the script below that runs normally, but when I turn it into a service to run on Windows it returns an unavailable URL. The script I transform and, executable using [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5) and install the service with `[nssm][2]` Has anyone caught this similar error?

```
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

while ($true) { 
    # Salvar o arquivo de log com a data atual
    $startTime =  (Get-Date).ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")
    $LogDate = ((get-date).ToLocalTime()).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")

    $list_acs = 
    @('https://IP:8081/login')

    # Loop para checar cada URL do Jboss
    Foreach ($url_acs in $list_acs)
    {

      try
      {
      $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url_acs
      $StatusCode = $WebResponse.StatusCode 
      if ($StatusCode -match "200") {
            $SavePath = "$LogDate - Servidor:$url_acs - Status:$StatusCode"
      }
  
      else { $SavePath = "$LogDate - Servidor:$url_acs - Status:$StatusCode - URL unavailable" }
  
      }

      catch [Exception]
      {
            $SavePath = "$LogDate - Servidor:$url_acs - URL unavailable!" 
      }
      $SavePath >> "C:\scripts_acs\logs\acs_$startTime.log"
    }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
}
```

Comment: Which service logon account are you using? If `LocalService`, try changing to `NetworkService`

Comment: Hello Mathias, in Log On I only have the options of Local System and This Account, the service is like Local system. I find it very strange that when I run the script directly from the Power Shell terminal it works correctly